# Git - ignore files by extension and include a dir that contains only these files

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to exclude all the jar files from git but include a directory (and its subdirectories) that contains only files of that type

I tried this in `.gitignore`

```
*.jar

!/lib/
```

but it doesn't work.

I see that it works with

```
*.jar

!/lib/
!/lib/*
```

or

```
*.jar

!/lib/**
```

but I don't understand why the first one doesn't work. Can someone explain me this behavior?

But refer to this, more in general, how can I be sure that all the files in a directory (and its subdirectories) will be included in git ignoring the previous exclusions in `.gitignore`?

Thanks for the help

Comment: in your first step you excluded *.jar and not subdirectories under /lib/, why it not worked is because !/lib/ will not recognize subdirs, two asterisk solve this as they including path separator for subdirs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "!*" > lib/.gitignore
```

is the simplest way to make this work.

What's going on is that `!` means "don't ignore something that a previous match to this pattern would tell you to ignore" -- and `/lib/` matches only directories.  No previous pattern tells git to ignore that directory.

An alternate way to explain it that I think is clearer is: excluding a directory tells git "don't even look here", which is subtly different to matching every file within.  Perhaps most clearly, if you had told it `/lib/`, git would never check (never even see) the `lib/.gitignore` above.  When you said '`!/lib/`' you told it to go ahead and look there, which it (would have anyway here, and) does.